# 'Uncaught (in promise): Error: Missing sender' when trying to send password reset link with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I ran into this issue when trying to send a firebase password reset email in my angular app after updating the firebase password reset template email.

An email was always present and the user existed in firebase but I still couldn't figure out what was causing this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the original answer to this problem [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/80)

The issue was that I updated the 'sender name' field in the firebase password reset template to be my company name. As an example it was similar to "Company XY, Inc" as seen in the photo below.

To fix the issue you simply need to remove the ',' from the sender field and then the error will go away.

FYI The same thing also happens if you include a ',' in the sender name field when using the firebase-email-trigger.

[image]